# How to listen/determine for active/topmost editor in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a notion of active or topmost editor in Eclipse?

I wrote a view and want it to show some data about active editor.

Currently I am using selection service, while editor is providing selection information. Unfortunately, this way I can't distinguish if editor was deselected or closed. So I am showing last selected editor information even after it was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IPartListener` (or `IPartListener2`) to be informed about all the changes to active parts.

```
IPartService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();

service.addPartListener(listener);
```

`IPartService` also has a `getActivePart()` method - the active part may be a view as well as an editor.

The above is assuming an Eclipse 3.x style RCP, Eclipse e4 is different.